# Need to Define Global Variable With Name "attacked_switches"

Tags: python, sdn, ddos

I'm using code from GitHub for mitigation of DDoS attacks using reactive flow rules in Floodlight Controller. I can't run the program because the global variable `attacked_switches` is not defined, but I don't know how to do that. Can anybody help me?

[From GitHub](https://github.com/rahulrajewar/cmpe210/blob/master/e.py)

[From YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JJ0Yi6Pvtno)

[Images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NVlH3.png)

```
def start():

    try:

        number_of_switches, number_of_hosts = topology_info()
        switch_dpids = list()
        hosts = dict()
        switch_dpids = switch_info(number_of_switches, switch_dpids)
        hosts = host_info(number_of_hosts, hosts)
        dpid = switch_byte(number_of_switches, switch_dpids)
        print 'dpid= ', dpid
        if dpid != 0:
            print'calling flow pusher'
            global attack
            attack = True
            attacked_switches.add(dpid)
            T2 = threading.Thread(target=Flowpusher, args=[dpid])
            T2.start()
        elif attack:
            T3 = threading.Thread(target=Flowremover, args=[dpid])
            T3.start()

    except Exception as e:
        print'Error occured:', e
```

Answer (score 0):

you can define a global variable simply by typing `global` before the variable name (before the first asignment of the variable). so:

```
global attacked_switches
```

See for example [here](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/global-keyword)

Edit: Looking at the github-code, assigning `attacked_switches` as a global variable won't help you. The code you reference has the line `attacked_switches.add(dpid)`, but I can't find where `attacked_switches` is defined.

Comment: Help you with what? With how to make attacked_switches global, that is easy and explained above. But the Github-code you showed in the link doesn't define attacked_switches anywhere. So you would have to define it somewhere (e.g. `attacked_switches = []`), but that where and how depends on what it is needed for.